# Javascript remove time from datetime

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar and using the date from the eventclick

```
calEvent._start._i         returns: 2015-12-01 09:00:00
```

and I want to compare it to another date although it is this format

```
2015-12-01
```

I have used

```
var date = new Date(calendarDate);
date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

which returns an invalid date format

I have also used

```
var calDate = _longDateFormat(calendarDate, "dd-mm-yy");
```

which errored on the javascript

Nothing seems to work, including dateFormat.

Ideas?

Comment: what do you want to compare? Two Dates ignoring the time?

Comment: Yes, at the moment becausae the times are different it doesn't work

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19054782/5089795

Comment: `if (requestedDate.sameDay(calendarDate)){
        return true;
    }`  when running through firebug it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem and I didn't want to use specific formatting options because I wanted the date to be displayed in the correct local format. I ended up using a simple regex replace, maybe this approach will help you as well:

```
new Date().toLocaleString().replace(/\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2,4}$/, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```js
function checkWhetherCorrectDate(requestedDate, calendarDate) {
    var date1 = new Date(calendarDate.replace(/-/g,'/'));
    var date2 = new Date(requestedDate);
    date1.setHours(date2.getHours(), date2.getMinutes(), date2.getSeconds());
    return date1.getTime() === date2.getTime();
}


document.write(checkWhetherCorrectDate("2015-12-01", "2015-11-30 09:00:00") + '<br />')
document.write(checkWhetherCorrectDate("2015-12-01", "2015-12-01 09:00:00") + '<br />')
```

Comment: `function checkWhetherCorrectDate(requestedDate, calendarDate){
    var date1 = new Date(calendarDate);
    var date2 = new Date(requestedDate);
    date1.setTime(date2.getTime());
    if (date1 == date2){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}`

This for some reasons made the dates the same. So calendarDate went from 30 nov to 1st dec.

Comment: requestedDate = 2015-12-01 and the calendarDate = 2015-11-30 09:00:00 after `date1.setTime(date2.getTime())` date1 = Tue Dec 01 2015 00:00:00

Comment: Ah ok, I see my error - setTime sets the time since january 1st 1970.  See my edit.  I have also changed your date comparing as it would always return false

Comment: I just tried your `setHours(0,0,0,0)` and it seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/futww3e2/

Comment: I can't understand why neither of these are doing anything. The solution you gave above formats date one as invalid.

Comment: It turns out your new Date(calendarDate) is what is failing - it was working for me as chrome is more flexible but ff and ie fail.  See edit above, should now work in all browsers